# Gsm modem submission rate

Tags: sms, gsm, throughput

Has anyone measured the rate of submission through a GSM modem? We are implementing a solution at the moment and are only able to submit at a rate of about one message every 3 to 5 seconds. We are not sure if this is a library/api problem or if our modem is just of poor quality. Has anyone had any experience with these devices and measured the throughput rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have implemented several system with GSM modems. You are seeing typical transmit rates for a GSM modem. 10-15 per minute is a rule of thumb I use. Consider adding additional modems to the pool and overlapping.

IF you can do SMS over GPRS you can get higher rates. But the implementations I've seen simply pool 3-5 modems in a single gateway. Any higher and you probably need to use an SMPP / SMSC link or a aggregator like Clickatel. The downside to the aggregators is coverage. You can't get delivery to some numbers, which is why I use GSM modems on ATT's network.